# Next Export does not generate any HTML files in /out dir

Tags: node.js, next.js

Operating System:  MAC M1

Binaries:
Node: 21.1.0

Relevant packages:

"next": "^14.0.1",

"react": "^18.2.0",

"react-dom": "^18",

"react-icons": "^4.11.0",

"swiper": "^11.0.4"

After I tried various ways from official doc or github issues, none of them worked out for this problem on my end..

here's the screenshots:
[next build console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwPRR.png)
[output dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTusj.png)

I tried this config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  output: 'export',
}

module.exports = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
}
```

from https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#unoptimized
but it didn't work either

Comment: have you tried installing 'sharp' package?